# Any type and implementing generic list in go programming language

Tags: go, oop, generics, interface

I'm trying a little of [go programming language](http://golang.org).

I'm a excited about the simplicity of the Go, but after playing with it I met some troubles.

1 . I know that *Go* doesn't support generics and inheritance. **Is there any way to implement generic list?**

I thinking about using:

```
type Any interface { }
```

but how can I check if the value is NULL.
I'm looking for some equivalent implementation to C

```
struct List {
  List* tail;
  void* head;
}
```

Or using algebraic datatype:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

2 . More advanced requirement would be to **make some container for objects with a field of a particular type?**
For example in *Scala programming language* I can type:

```
val List[Animal { type SuitableFood = Grass} ]
```

to get a `List` of `Animals`, which have a member type `SuitableFood` which is `Grass`

Answer (score 3):

You can have a list of elements of type `interface{}`. You can put any elements in, and when you get it out, you have to cast back to the type you want. This is like what you're doing `void *` in your C example; and also like lists in Java before Generics, and in Objective-C, which doesn't have generics. All the containers in the Go library do this.

Without generics, there is no compile-time checking of the element types.

If you really wanted, you could implement run-time checks for element type, by using reflection to get the element types and checking them against the expected type. However, this is probably overkill.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that Go doesn't support generics [...]

It does as of Go 1.18. I expect the standard library to eventually add generic containers along the current [`container/list`](https://pkg.go.dev/container/list) package so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Anyway as a thought exercise you could copy the standard `list.List` and add type parameters yourself:

```
type Element[T any] struct {
    next, prev  *Element[T]
    list        *List[T]
    Value       T
}

type List[T any] struct {
    root Element[T]
    len  int
}

// simplified constructor
func New[T any]() *List[T] { 
    l := new(List[T])
    l.root.next = &l.root
    l.root.prev = &l.root
    l.len = 0
    return l
}
```

As you can see `Element` struct can have a field of type `Element`, but the type params must be the same ones and in the same order ([source](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#generic-types)).

> make some container for objects with a field of a particular type?

You can do this by replacing the constraint `any` with an interface constraint that specified the method you want, for example:

```
type Animal interface { 
    SuitableFood() string 
}

type Element[T Animal] struct {
    // ...
}
```

and this constrains the type parameter to those that implement the `Animal` interface.

---

What you can **not** do is constrain the type param to have a particular **field**<sup>1</sup>. If you must force `T` to have specific values, you could instead add a more specific method to the interface constraint, e.g.  `SuitableFoodGrass()` but that's a *leaky abstraction*. Interfaces model behavior, and you should stick to that principle.

---

<sup>1: Technically you can, using a type constraint with a struct, but it wouldn't be very useful</sup>.